# Workaround for 'cut' when it's piped a few lines with differing pattern from grep?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, grep

This is a work in progress and I'm looking for advice from someone with more knowledge (computers are a hobby of mine, not my major).

This script is meant to organize a directory of television shows (renaming each file to the convention *S01E01.Title of Episode.ext* and creating a symbolic link of the original name).

I enjoy writing this, and I don't expect others to dedicate too much of their time. I guess my biggest "stumpers" right now are:

1. Fix the occurence of "<_a href=" (minus underline) from grep+cut output.
2. Grab correct textblock with awk from wiki (according to season#)

   (also, if anything looks inefficient, please let me know-- I'm learning)

I've been on these forums left and right, making progress as I go. I've exhausted most of the similar questions to mine. (these forums are 100% the reason I've built this this far).

```
## Find show name and season (directories nested: /show/season)
show1=$(cd .. ; pwd)
show="${show1##*/}"
season=("${PWD##*/}")

IFS=$'\n'

## Download list of episodes for given season
wget -q -O- --header\="Accept-Encoding: gzip" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_$show\_episodes | gunzip > tmp.html

## Working on first awk/sed command to grab textblock of only specific season
## grep command works great, except when episode is hyperlinked ('a href' tag gets cut)
if [ "$season" == 'Season 1' ]; then
        listing=( $(awk '/\(season_1\)/,/rellink/' tmp.html | grep "summary.*[\"]<" | cut -d'"' -f6) )
        unset IFS
elif [ "$season" == 'Season 2' ]; then
        listing=( $(awk '/\(season_2\)/,/rellink/' tmp.html | grep "summary.*[\"]<" | cut -d'"' -f6) )
        unset IFS
#..........................continued 20 times or so
fi
```

I've been making so many adjustments to the code above that this second half has to be completed afterwards; but it did work 90% before. The only problem was that it would name some files *S01E05.ahref=.mkv* if they were hyperlinked on the wikipedia page (because of cut).

```
## Parse filename for season/episode descriptor
## Rename file with season/episode and name from wikipedia database
for file in *
do
    name=$(ls "$file" | grep -o "S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9]")
    episode=$(ls "$file" | grep -o "E[0-9][0-9]")
        if [ "$episode" == 'E01' ]; then
                mv "$file" "$name.${listing[0]}.mkv"
                ln -s "$name.${listing[0]}.mkv" "$file"
                echo "Renamed '$file' and created a symbolic link."
        #..........................continued
        fi
done
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of input filenames and what you're trying to get?

Comment: As your learning, I'd suggest researching [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath) so that you can use combinations like [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/)/[Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) to do your screen scraping and file creation.  Tools like [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox variants then let you inspect a page and read the XPath value of table elements directly for your scripts.  There are many languages with XPath parsers, and many browsers/plugins that can examine pages.  Pick out those you want to learn and have fun!

Comment: @BroSlow The folder structure is ~/ShowTitle/Season #/ The files always contain 'S01E01' (depending on season# & ep#)(ie. foo-S03E11.mkv, foo S05E02.mkv, foo_S05E24.mkv).I'd like to download a show's page from wikipedia (specific to parent dir name), and find the season section in the html file (specific to current dir name) and save this to an array. Then rename each file to S01E01.Show Title.mkv and create a symbolic link with the original name.

Comment: @n0741337 Thank you for the tip, I will look into XPath. I have been considering learning Python/Ruby, I'm sure they make it very easy to do this task. This script is just too close to working perfectly; I don't want to quit just yet :P

Comment: @gpops So at this point you're essentially trying to parse wiki for a particular show and get all episodes with pertaining title number, season, description, and whatever else? Also looking at wiki html, it shouldn't be too hard to loop line by line, and just pase out title, episode, etc... (Meaning why do you have 20 or so if/else blocks)

Comment: @BroSlow Yes, and put into an array in order. I was 90% successful parsing the name, except for a few when the episode is linked on the wikipedia page; the extra html messes with the regex in grep|cut. I also need to fix my awk to grab the correct section by season. And I'll change the if/else blocks to a loop, thank you for that advice.

Comment: @gpops I think my answer should get most of what you want. Rather than printing the titles, just add them to array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with the comments, that `bash` isn't the way to go when parsing webpages or html. But if you've already started and want to do it in bash then it's not impossible. Looking at your code, I Like your use of bash substitution and globing, but a bit confused on how it all goes together, so wrote a simple version of my own you can hopefully interpolate or work off of.

```
#!/bin/bash

show="Archer"
url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_${show}_episodes"

while read line; do
  [[ $line =~ "<h3><span class=\"mw-headline\" id=\"Season" ]] && episode= && ((
  if [[ $line =~ "<td class=\"summary\" style=\"text-align: left;\">\""(.*)"\""

    title="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    [[ "$title" =~ "title=\""(.*)"\"" ]] && title="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    title="${title%%\"*}"
    title="$(echo ${title/($show)/})"

    echo "Season [$season] Episode [$((episode+=1))] Title [$title]"
  fi
done < <(wget -qO- "$url")
```

Example Output: (also tested with `scrubs` and `simpsons` getting correct results)

```
Season [1] Episode [1] Title [Mole Hunt]
Season [1] Episode [2] Title [Training Day]
Season [1] Episode [3] Title [Diversity Hire]
Season [1] Episode [4] Title [Killing Utne]
Season [1] Episode [5] Title [Honeypot]
Season [1] Episode [6] Title [Skorpio]
Season [1] Episode [7] Title [Skytanic]
Season [1] Episode [8] Title [The Rock]
Season [1] Episode [9] Title [Job Offer]
Season [1] Episode [10] Title [Dial M for Mother]
Season [2] Episode [1] Title [Swiss Miss]
Season [2] Episode [2] Title [A Going Concern]
Season [2] Episode [3] Title [Blood Test]
Season [2] Episode [4] Title [Pipeline Fever]
Season [2] Episode [5] Title [The Double Deuce]
Season [2] Episode [6] Title [Tragical History]
Season [2] Episode [7] Title [Movie Star]
Season [2] Episode [8] Title [Stage Two]
Season [2] Episode [9] Title [Placebo Effect]
Season [2] Episode [10] Title [El Secuestro]
Season [2] Episode [11] Title [Jeu Monégasque]
Season [2] Episode [12] Title [White Nights]
Season [2] Episode [13] Title [Double Trouble]
Season [3] Episode [1] Title [Heart of Archness: Part I]
Season [3] Episode [2] Title [Heart of Archness: Part II]
Season [3] Episode [3] Title [Heart of Archness: Part III]
Season [3] Episode [4] Title [The Man from Jupiter]
Season [3] Episode [5] Title [El Contador]
Season [3] Episode [6] Title [The Limited]
Season [3] Episode [7] Title [Drift Problem]
Season [3] Episode [8] Title [Lo Scandalo]
Season [3] Episode [9] Title [Bloody Ferlin]
Season [3] Episode [10] Title [Crossing Over]
Season [3] Episode [11] Title [Skin Game]
Season [3] Episode [12] Title [Space Race]
Season [3] Episode [13] Title [Space Race]
Season [4] Episode [1] Title [Fugue and Riffs]
Season [4] Episode [2] Title [The Wind Cries Mary]
Season [4] Episode [3] Title [Legs]
Season [4] Episode [4] Title [Midnight Ron]
Season [4] Episode [5] Title [Viscous Coupling]
Season [4] Episode [6] Title [Once Bitten]
Season [4] Episode [7] Title [Live and Let Dine]
Season [4] Episode [8] Title [Coyote Lovely]
Season [4] Episode [9] Title [The Honeymooners]
Season [4] Episode [10] Title [Un Chien Tangerine]
Season [4] Episode [11] Title [The Papal Chase]
Season [4] Episode [12] Title [Sea Tunt: Part I]
Season [4] Episode [13] Title [Sea Tunt: Part II]
Season [5] Episode [1] Title [White Elephant]
Season [5] Episode [2] Title [Archer Vice: A Kiss While Dying]
Season [5] Episode [3] Title [Archer Vice: A Debt of Honor]
Season [5] Episode [4] Title [Archer Vice: House Call]
Season [5] Episode [5] Title [Archer Vice: Southbound and Down]
```

**Explanation**:

I find `BASH_REMATCH` useful in a lot of cases like this where you have to match substrings and don't want to figure out some crazy regex.

```
BASH_REMATCH
  An array variable whose members are assigned by the =~ binary operator to the [[ conditional  command.   The  element
  with  index  0  is the portion of the string matching the entire regular expression.  The element with index n is the
  portion of the string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression.  This variable is read-only.
```

Otherwise, main issues were as you noted, that title format can differ. So I just did another `BASH_REMATCH` for cases when it's a href (when it will have a `title` attribute), and removed the trailing text in odd cases when the episode hasn't come out yet. Maybe some other cases, but this worked on all 3 shows I tested on.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your help! I've been trying to dissect your code and learn from it. I'm almost done the script now. I'll post it as an answer once completed.

Comment: The only additional thing: the BASH_REMATCH works 99%, but when the HTML looks like "title="Training Day (Archer)">Training Day</a>"</li>".... "Training Day (Archer)" is grabbed (wiki is specifying which 'Training Day', since there is a movie, episode, book). Can you adjust it further?

Comment: @gpops You're always going to have those types of problems when parsing html, especially when it's a multi-user site. I added case to strip `($title)` and surrounding whitespace. There's definitely a simpler/less error-prone syntax, but that's the simplest one I could come up with off the top of my head. The problem with matching between `>(.*)<` is I don't think there's a way to make BASH_REMATCH non-greedy, so sticking with above is probably less error-prone and less work than re-writing it to use some perl style matching.

Comment: Very cool. It works flawlessly now. Again, I appreciate the help and explaining. I learned a lot from this.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest a **multi-platform web-scraping CLI** that doesn't seem to get enough attention: **[xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html#downloads)**

It supports the Xpath 2, CSS 3, XQuery 1, JSONiq query languages.

Used with a simplified version of the scenario at hand, we get the following, which hopefully gives you a sense of how much easier scraping becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Example values.
show='Archer'
season=2

# Synthesize the URL to scrape.
url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_${show}_episodes"

# The XPath expression for extracting the specified season's episode titles
qryEpisodeTitles="//*[matches(@id, '^Season_$season')]
/../following-sibling::table[1]//td[@class='summary']"

# Scrape the page at the URL and read all episode titles 
# (including enclosing " chars.) into an array.
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra episodeTitles <<<"$(xidel -e "$qryEpisodeTitles" "$url")"

# Enumerate all episode titles with an index.
# Note: Typically, episodes are enclosed in literal `"` chars.; additionally,
#       after the closing `"`, they may contain footnote references, such as
#       `[2]` or `†`, so some cleaning-up may be required.
i=0
for episodeTitle in "${episodeTitles[@]}"; do 
  echo "Episode $((++i)): $episodeTitle"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to BroSlow's help (and code!) the script is complete.

```
#!/bin/bash

show1=$(cd .. ; pwd)
show="${show1##*/}"
seas1="${PWD##*/}"
seas=$(echo $seas1 | grep -o "[0-9][0-9]*")
url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_$show\_episodes
IFS=$'\n'

while read line; do
[[ $line =~ "<h3><span class=\"mw-headline\" id=\"Season" ]] && episode= && ((season+=1))
  if [[ $line =~ "<td class=\"summary\" style=\"text-align: left;\">\""(.*)"\"" ]]; then

  title="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  [[ "$title" =~ "title=\""(.*)"\"" ]] && title="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  title="${title%%\"*}"
  title="$(echo ${title/($show)/})"

  arrTitle+=( "${season}.${title}" )
  fi
done < <(wget -qO- "$url")

## Make new array of only specific season ($seas=current dirname).
## Remove # in front of name with 'cut'
for i in "${arrTitle[@]}"; do
  if [[ $i == $seas.* ]]; then 
  arrNewTitle+=( $(echo $i | cut -d '.' -f2))
  fi
done

n=-1

for file in *; do 
  $((n+=1)) 
  name=$(grep -o "S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9]" <<< "$file") 
  mv "$file" "$name.${arrNewTitle[n]}.mkv"
  ln -s "$name.${arrNewTitle[n]}.mkv" "$file"
  echo "Renamed '$file' and created a symbolic link."
done

## Remove script when done, and its symbolic link (z to be at bottom of filelist)
rm 'z_rename.sh' '..mkv'
```

Comment: A couple of possible bugs/simplifications, change `ls "$file" | grep -o "S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9]"` to `grep -o "S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9]" <<< "$file"`. Also unless there is some setting in bash I'm not aware of (entirely possible) your math operations won't work as expected. e.g. `((n+=1))` increments variable `n` by 1, `$((n+=1))` increments variable `n` by 1 and returns `n` after increment, `n+=1` by itself concatenates 1. Otherwise looks pretty snappy.

Comment: Also `arrTitle+=( $season.$title )` should probably be `arrTitle+=("${season}.${title}")` So you don't get bad splitting as a result of unquoted variables.